# IE8 and reading XML via AJAX

Tags: php, xml, ajax, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I have a store locator, built using Google Maps, PHP/Mysql and jQuery here:
http://tinyurl.com/4w8nwwp

Everything is dandy in FF, Safari,Chrome and Opera.
IE7, 8 cannot read the XML that is dynamically generated by `parse_location.php`

The AJAX code:

```
function reloadMap(map, dataString) {
    markersArray = [];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "loading...", maxWidth:100});
    var storeListHtml = '<h2>Name <span style="margin-left:252px;">Address</span></h2><ul>';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "parse_location.php",
    data: dataString,

    success: function(text){

        count = -1;


        $(text).find("list").each(function()
        {
            count++;
            if(count == 0)
            {
                var burnsvilleMN = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr("lat"),$(this).attr("lng"));
                map.panTo(burnsvilleMN);
            }

            var store = [$(this).attr("name"), $(this).attr("address"), $(this).attr("lat"), $(this).attr("lng"), count];

            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var address = $(this).attr("address");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr("lat"),$(this).attr("lng"));
            var html = "<span class='info'><b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "</span>";
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/icon_dot2.png');
            var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/icon_dot_shadow.png');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: image,
                shadow:shadow
                //shadow: icon.shadow
            });

            //markersArray.push(marker);

            storeListHtml += "<li class='store'><a href='javascript:myclick("+count+")'><div class='store-name'>"+name+"</div><div class='store-add'> "+address+"</div></a></li>";


            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }); 
        storeListHtml += '</ul>';

        $("#store-list").html(storeListHtml);
    }
});
```

}

As you can see, this involves calling parse_location.php, getting the XML generated by this code:
         // uncommenting the following line causes ff, safari et al to not show anything.
     // header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

```
$responce = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$responce .= "<location>\n"; 
$city = $_GET['city'];
$category = $_GET['category'];
```

[SQL Query here ]

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $responce .= "<list name=\"".$row["name"]."\" 
            address=\"".$row["street_address"]." ".$row["city"]." ".$row["state"].", ".$row["zip"]."\" 
            lat=\"".$row["lat"]."\" 
            lng=\"".$row["lng"]."\" />";




}



$responce .= "</location>";
$responce8 = utf8_encode($responce);
echo $responce8;
```

Any pointers???

Rishi

Comment: You should add a blank line before and after your code snippets to ensure they get properly formatted. Besides that: have you tried opening the script's URL directly through IE's address bar? It'd help a lot to know whether the issue is about the content, or the xhr request itself.

Comment: hey herenvardo, thanks for the tips, I will definitely format code better, this is my first time posting code in a question. 

That said, I tried running parse_location.php directly, and I just output user agent on that page. don't really know what to make out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Content-Type` header to your php code like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml'); // Try "application/xml" too
```

Also, adding another IE-specific header might help:

```
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

You need to do this before outputting anything else of course, since they are [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Thanks Jon, I tried both, the first one, header('Content-Type: text/xml'); actually limits some results from been displayed in FF/Chrome/Safari. The IE-specific header did not work in IE8. I'm thinking its special characters (?) in the Store names?

Comment: @frishi: Special characters shouldn't matter: you are encoding in UTF-8 and also telling the browser, so it knows how to decode.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I've gotten two cities to display listings: San Diego and Austin. All other locations are still missing.

Comment: Additionally, when I remove the header line, everything works as it should in FF/Chrome/Safari. And IE8 gets nothing.

Comment: @frishi: What's different about the two cities that you *can* get to display?

Comment: The only pattern I can find is that the number of locations is less than 30. They do contain names with accents, so it can't be the special characters.